# AppIcon not Set

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I want to set my appIcon.I am drag an image in app-icon. They show on target everywhere on app. but not set on appicon. And my appicon source is appicon.

[image]
[image: this is my app icon image![][1]]

Comment: In project-->targets-->general-->App Icon source have you set that ?

Comment: You were not able to see the icons on simulator or on device?

Comment: @NileshPatel on device

Comment: you must have tried installing it after deleting the existing one, Right?

Comment: Okay.. Are you getting any kind of warning for Image asset?? It might be possible that by mistake you have set wrong size icon at wrong place..

Answer (score 1):

Please check you build setting for App Icons setting. I have attached a screenshot for the same.

[image]

Comment: Please check this link from apple. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013303-CH1-SW1

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your App Icons have true targets? Can you check the image sizes you put into App Icons field?

Comment: You should convert your AppIcon size to available sizes given under  the AppIcon images. Such as 29pt - 40pt - 60pt.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your icons are added in Copy Bundle Resources

App Target ->Build Phases-> Copy Bundle Resources

If Icons are not in the list then it will not copy to device so you may not able to see the icon.

Hope this will help you.